# I have an XML manifest file of time signatures to play MP3 files. Can I use PHP to combine these MP3's into one master MP3 file?

Tags: php, mp3

I imagine the XML will look something like this:

```
 <xml>
   <node time="500">1.mp3</node>
   <node time="700">2.mp3</node>
   <node time="800">3mp3</node>
   <node time="900">1.mp3</node>
   <node time="1000">2.mp3</node>
   <node time="1100">3.mp3</node>
 </xml>
```

Time would be in milliseconds. I am new to PHP, and I'm not sure if a library exists that would allow me to sequence these MP3s.

Answer (score 0):

As mp3 files are just frames you could remove the ID3 tags front and back and then use normal php script to basically stitch the filestreams together. They will click but it would give you  essentially a 0 latency playback albeit from a file stream. If the answer involves playing one after another using php as some sort of file system then no.

Comment: If you wanted to have one file on server and then divy it up from a php file you could using $_GET or $_POST method and handle the attached variable accordingly then use filestream to send the contents of that bit of a file. There wouldnt be any point though as any server space you would save (negligible) wouldnt be worth the complication of the script to fish them out.

Comment: I'll need to sequence them based on millisecond start times. This means that they will likely overlap, and multiple sound layers may exist.

Comment: the smallest unit of an mp3 file is a frame, which is 0.028 seconds. you'll have to account for that with your start/end times. splitting a frame is not possible unless you convert back to raw pcm and split at that level, then re-encode the new merged chunk of audio to an mp3 frame.

Comment: You cant do what you are trying to in php, unless you are expecting the server to mix these in realtime? which would be a massive PITA and you would hit the script limit/memory limit and latency would be out of the window. The only technology I'm aware of that would allow you to do this would be Flash and we all know how popular that idea is going to be.

Comment: Also Marc B, sorry to be a pedant but the frames in an mp3 can be any length depending on bitrate, frequency of the audio, type of encoding CBR/VBR etc. But you are right about splitting frames, once you chunk into the compliant bitstream you get nothing but junk until another valid frame is found. If you stitched files together even if you messed up a frame you would only lose that one frame resulting in a slight skip in the audio and nothing more than that.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback everyone. The application creating this XML manifest is actually Flash. Flash is also the only solution that will allow users to custom mix their own songs, and save them as XML. I'm trying to come up with a solution for mobile users who can't use the Flash mix player. I was hoping to generate MP3's that they could listen to.